# Clean way to show specific trigonometric integral is finite

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, estimation, trigonometric-integrals

Let $K\geq2$ be some constant. Then I would like to show that the following integral is finite:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}(1/K)} \int_{\theta}^{2\cos^{-1}(1-K\sin(\theta)) - \theta} \frac{\sin ^{2}\left(\frac{\theta+\varphi}{2}\right)}{\sin \theta \sin \varphi} d \varphi d \theta.
\end{equation}

**What I have tried:**
I have tried to use the identity
$$\frac{\sin ^{2}\left(\frac{\theta+\varphi}{2}\right)}{\sin \theta \sin \varphi} = \frac{\sin\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)\cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)}{4\cos\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)\sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\cos\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)\sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)}{4\sin\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)\cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)}$$
to split up the integral as follows
$$\int_{0}^{\theta_{0}} \int_{\theta}^{2\cos^{-1}(1-K\sin(\theta)) - \theta} \frac{\sin\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)\cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)}{4\cos\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)\sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)}d \varphi d \theta \\+ \int_{0}^{\theta_{0}} \int_{\theta}^{2\cos^{-1}(1-K\sin(\theta)) - \theta}\frac{\cos\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)\sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)}{4\sin\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right)\cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right)} d \varphi d \theta + \frac{\pi^2}{2}.$$
Then in both integrals I first work out the inner integral (so with respect to $\varphi$). Then the for remaining integrals with variable $\theta$ I try to argue with for example L'Hôpital's rule and Taylor expansions of trigonometric functions at $\theta = 0$ and at $\theta = \sin(1/K)$ that the integrands are equal to $0$ in the integration bounds. After that I argue that the integrands are continuous on the rest of the integration intervals and thus conclude that the integrands are bounded and thus also the integrals.

**My question:** The above method seems really quite complicated. I am wondering if there is an easier way to show that
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}(1/K)} \int_{\theta}^{2\cos^{-1}(1-K\sin(\theta)) - \theta} \frac{\sin ^{2}\left(\frac{\theta+\varphi}{2}\right)}{\sin \theta \sin \varphi} d \varphi d \theta
\end{equation}
is finite. For example with just a direct sequence of estimates from above or some other significantly less complicated method.

Many thanks in advance.